# Generate html report from .coverage file

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose, python-coverage

I'm looking for a way to combine multiple .coverage files and then generate an html report.
Currently I'm generating coverage just from one source with the following command and it works fine:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-html --cover-html-dir=/var/www/coverage
```

Now I want to start by splitting the process in two:

1. Generate coverage report (.coverage file)
2. Generate html report from .coverage file

First step is clear, same command as before ommiting the html part.
Then I've seen in many places to just run `coverage html`, including [python coverage package website](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/).
When I do that I obtain a console-printed report of my coverage and the following

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named html)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 402, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 311, in resolve_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: No module named html
```

It's like nose is interfering somehow:

```
$ coverage report -m
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: -m option requires an argument

$ coverage --help
Usage: nosetests [options]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your coverage package is not installed properly. Try running `pip freeze` to see if you have a standalone `coverage==3.5.3` or equivalent installed. If you do not have anything, try `pip install coverage`. Once installed you will have access to `coverage` binary in python binary utilities folder, rather what looks like nosetests alias.

Comment: Ok, I feel really dumb, I had an alias for coverage and I didn't know about it